# DataFrame Pandas - Calcular coluna com base em outras

Tags: python, algoritmo, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um dataframe no seguinte formato:

```
colunas = [
    'COMEDY',
    'CRIME',
    'Classe Prevista'
]

precisao_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=colunas)
precisao_df['COMEDY'] = y_pred_proba[:,0]
precisao_df['CRIME'] = y_pred_proba[:,1]
precisao_df
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quero fazer o seguinte: para cada linha, se comedy > crime, classe prevista = comedy, senão crime. Ou seja, a classe prevista é a que meu modelo deu mais probabilidade de ser. Como posso fazer essa expressão?

Ex:

```
    COMEDY    CRIME      Classe prevista
0    0.9       0.1          COMEDY
1    0.42      0.58         CRIME
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie uma função que determina a classe que você quer colocar na coluna:

```
def acha_classe(registro):
    if registro['COMEDY'] > registro['CRIME']:
        return 'COMEDY'
    elif registro['COMEDY'] < registro['CRIME']:
        return 'CRIME'
    else:
        return 'UNKNOWN'
```

Basta agora aplicar (`apply`) essa função:

```
df['Classe Prevista'] = df.apply(acha_classe, axis=1)
```

Comment: muito bom, obrigada! a única coisa que precisei fazer foi mudar o que vc colocou `df` pra `precisao_df`, mas funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar a função [**`where`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) o pacote *NumPy*, basta informar uma condição e os valores a serem utilizados caso verdadeiro ou falso.

```
df['Classe Prevista'] = np.where(df.COMEDY > df.CRIME, 'COMEDY', 'CRIME')
#                                                         |        |
#                                                         - True   |
#                                                                  -  False
```

Saída:

```
     COMEDY     CRIME Classe Prevista
0  0.909657  0.090343          COMEDY
1  0.180432  0.819568           CRIME
2  0.756018  0.243982          COMEDY
```

Veja funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/@wellmotta/pt-stackoverflow-340114)

Comment: Na verdade o `pandas` também tem `where`... `df['Classe Prevista'].where(df.COMEDY>df.CRIME, 'COMEDY', inplace=True)` `df['Classe Prevista'].where(df.COMEDY<df.CRIME, 'CRIME', inplace=True)`