# Warning looping Python Pandas, Como fazer o looping de forma diferente?

Tags: python, loop, pandas, warnings

Pessoal estou fazer este looping aqui:

```
for i in range(1, len(candles)):
    if candles['askclose'][i]> candles['askopen'][i]:
        candles['Fechamento'][i]= 'alta'
```

Mas o jupyternotebook me retorna sempre este warning e às vezes trava e não avança, alguma ideia de como melhorar ou fazer diferente este looping, para evitar o warning:

```
Warning:

C:\Users\Jair\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
```

A mascara como o amigo sugeriu é otima solução, mas e quando eu tiver um loop maior como este:

```
for i in range(1, len(candles)):
    tamanho_twin = 0
    if candles['Fechamento'][i]=='baixa' and candles['Fechamento'][i-1] == 'alta':
        if candles['askclose'][i] <= candles['askopen'][i-1] and candles['MA20'][i]<candles['MA20'][i-2]:
            limite_sombraV= ((candles['askclose'][i]-candles['askopen'][i])*0.1)+candles['askclose'][i]
            if candles['asklow'][i] == limite_sombraV:
                tamanho_twin = candles['askclose'][i]+candles['askopen'][i]
                candles['Twintower'][i] = 0
                candles['Tamanho_Twin'][i] = candles['askclose'][i]+candles['askopen'][i]
```

Comment: Não poderia fazer apenas: `candles['Fechamento'] = np.where(candles.askclose > candles.askopen, 'alta', '')`, nem precisará do laço `for`.

Comment: Aqui uma pergunta semelhante: [DataFrame Pandas - Calcular coluna com base em outras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/340114)

Comment: Dá para vc mostrar "candles"? faça um print (`print(candles)`) e mostre o resultado, ou parte dele.

Comment: Desculpe, agora virou uma outra pergunta.

Comment: @NoobSaibot, não por que preciso tambem incluir o invesrso para  'baixa'

Comment: @JairMiranda é só colocar o terceiro parâmetro: `candles['Fechamento'] = np.where(candles.askclose > candles.askopen, 'alta', 'baixa')`, o primeiro é a condição, segundo e terceiro são os valores que serão aplicados caso a condição seja verdadeiro ou falsa.

Comment: @NoobSaibot tem um problema só eu tenho a terceira situação, onde candles.askclose=candles.askopen, ai neste caso nao sei como aplicar o np.where

Comment: @NoobSaibot, sao 3 situaçãos: candles.askclose > candles.askopen: alta, candles.askclose < candles.askopen: 'baixa, candles.askclose > candles.askopen: 'neutro'

Comment: @JairMiranda faz assim: `candles['Fechamento'] = np.where(
  candles.askclose < candles.askopen,
  'baixa',
  np.where(candles.askclose == candles.askopen, 'neutro', 'alta'))`

Comment: @NoobSaibot, sua solução foi fantastica, usei para absolutamente todos os loopings, muitooo obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi a questão vc só precisa de uma máscara, veja:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [[1,2,'n/a'],[2,1,'n/a'],[3,4,'n/a'],[4,3,'n/a']]
candles = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['askclose', 'askopen', 'fechamento'])

print('Candles original', candles, sep='\n')
Candle original
   askclose  askopen fechamento
0         1        2        n/a
1         2        1        n/a
2         3        4        n/a
3         4        3        n/a

# Criação da mascara
mask = candles.askopen>candles.askclose

# Atualização do candles
candles.loc[mask, 'fechamento'] = 'alta'

print('Candles atualizado', candles, sep='\n')
Candles atualizado
   askclose  askopen fechamento
0         1        2       alta
1         2        1        n/a
2         3        4       alta
3         4        3        n/a
```

**Obs.:**
Para atribuir um valor diferente quando `askopen` for menor, crie uma segunda mascara ou negue a mascara criada com um operador bitwise (`candles.loc[~mask, 'fechamento'] = 'baixa'`)

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-mask-1)

> Editada 
>  
>   Depois da sua edição à pergunta entendi que a sua necessidade é iterar o dataframe, criei uma função que itera o `df` recebido e o altera baseado no valor anterior de uma coluna, para simplificar utilizei valores numericos e nomes de colunas baseados nas 3 primeira letras (a, b, c). É só adaptar à sua necessidade.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def iter_df(df):
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        if i !=0: 
            print('indice atual: ',i, 'coluna: a')
            print('valor atual :', df.iloc[i]['a'], 'valor anterior: ', 
                   df.iloc[i-1]['a'])
            print('-'*36)

        # Alterando o valor de uma coluna baseado no valor do indice anterior
        if df.iloc[i-1]['a']==11:
            df.iloc[i]['a']=99
    return df 

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33], [41, 42, 43]])
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

print ('df antes da atualizacao', df, sep='\n')
df antes da atualizacao
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  11  12  13
2  21  22  23
3  31  32  33
4  41  42  43

print ('df pós atualizacao', iter_df(df),sep='\n' )
indice atual:  1 coluna: a
valor atual : 11 valor anterior:  1
------------------------------------
indice atual:  2 coluna: a
valor atual : 21 valor anterior:  11
------------------------------------
indice atual:  3 coluna: a
valor atual : 31 valor anterior:  21
------------------------------------
indice atual:  4 coluna: a
valor atual : 41 valor anterior:  31
------------------------------------
df pós atualizacao
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  11  12  13
2  99  22  23
3  31  32  33
4  41  42  43
```

Veja essa [nova versão no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-iter-rows-2)

Comment: Muito Obrigado, mas da uma olhada no que adicionei acima, quando for dar um looping maior

Comment: Ok, mas vc mudou totalmente a pergunta e colocou um codigo que não funciona, consegue simular um dataframe para rodar com o codigo?

Comment: Mesmo sem entender claramente o que vc quer, elaborei uma nova versão da resposta, vou editar essa, veja se atende agora.

Comment: Muito obrigado, entao eu tenho varias iterações mas com diferentes condiçoes, a ideia é achar padroes dentro de um dataframe, então eu vou ter que achar uma solução em que eu consiga adaptar para outras condiçoes, gostei muito da sua primeira solução bem pythonica, vou tentar adapatar ela para uma condição maior e posto aqui pra ti!

Comment: Para achar padrões em dados nos dias de hoje é bem fácil, utilize uma rede neural simples (com poucas camadas). Em python temos um excelente framework: [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/).

Comment: ele substituiria estas condiçoes que quero criar? Tipo eu defino um padrão e quero que toda vez que ele ache o padrão, ele faça x atividade, mas não é graficamente, é lendo dados.

Comment: Redes neurais identificam padrões somente (o que não é pouco), o algoritmo para processar os padrões vc teria que fazer, mas acho que minha segunda solução faz exatamente o que vc pede depois que editou a pergunta.

Comment: Li aqui sobre redes neurais a um tempo atras, ja esotu fazendo o curso, comecei assim que li sua observação, acho que vai ser perfeito e vai permitir uma evolução do sistema de forma mais abrangente complexa e correta, pois a rede neural faz exatamente oque eu quero, ja que quero que após 3 ou 5 condições ele me de um padrão, nada melhor que filtrar pelos 'neuronios', so vou me dedicar sabado e domingo para terminar o curso do pytorch e aplicar aqui

Comment: Se a resposta lhe foi util, peço-lhe que dê o aceite e o upvote. :-)