# DataFrame - Pandas. Criando nova coluna após comparação entre colunas

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho o seguinte df

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso adicionar o código da coluna CODIGO, na coluna cod_cidade nos casos que o valor da coluna ds_cidade seja igual a coluna LOCALIDADADE.

Já tentei dessa forma, mas não rolou:

```
def acha_codigo(registro):
    if registro['ds_cidade'] == registro['LOCALIDADE']:
        return registro['CODIGO']
    else:
        return 'UNKNOWN'
```

Resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc diz que precisa "adiconar o código da coluna COLUNA, na coluna cod_cidade", dá para explicar melhor isso? Não vi nenuma coluna chamada COLUNA. :-) Seria interesante vc dar um print no df e colocar o resultado ao invés da imagem. Fica mais facil para ajudar.

Comment: Opa, erro meu. E da coluna CODIGO. Essa imagem é um print do df.head()

Comment: Então... Sempre coloca o resultado do print (contrl-c/control-v) ao inves da imagem, assim quem tentar ajudar pode aproveitar para fazer testes.

Comment: Seria interessante tb, q vc colocasse como quer que fique no final.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [DataFrame Pandas - Calcular coluna com base em outras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/340114/dataframe-pandas-calcular-coluna-com-base-em-outras)

Comment: Ah, entendi @Sidon. Vou fazer isso.

Comment: @AlexCiuffa Acho que esta relacionado, mas não acho que seja duplicata.

Comment: Agora que o problema ficou mais claro, realmente vi que não é duplicata.

Answer (score 2):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-iter-row-chg-col)

Na imagem do seu exemplo, não tem nenhuma conicidencia entre as colunas `LOCALIDADE`e `ds_cidade`, por isso criei um `DataFrame` em que uma das linhas tem essas colunas conicidentes, então crio uma nova coluna (`nova_coluna`), faço uma iteração no `df` para checar se há coincidencias nos valores das colunas citadas, se sim, altero o valor da `nova_coluna` para o valor da coluna `CODIGO`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [(5200050, 'ABADIA DE GOIAS', 'GO', 'NAN', 'ABAETETUBA'), 
        (3100104, 'ABADIA DOS DOURADOS', 'MG', 'NAN', 'ABAETETUBA'),
        (5200100, 'ABADIANA', 'GO', 'NAN', 'ABADIANA'),
        (3100203, 'ABAETE', 'MG', 'NAN', 'ABAETETUBA'),
        (1500107, 'ABETETUBA', 'GO', 'NAN', 'ABAETETUBA')]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['CODIGO', 'LOCALIDADE', 'UF', 'cod_cidade', 'ds_cidade'])

print(df)
```

Saída:

```
    CODIGO           LOCALIDADE  UF cod_cidade   ds_cidade
0  5200050      ABADIA DE GOIAS  GO        NAN  ABAETETUBA
1  3100104  ABADIA DOS DOURADOS  MG        NAN  ABAETETUBA
2  5200100             ABADIANA  GO        NAN    ABADIANA
3  3100203               ABAETE  MG        NAN  ABAETETUBA
4  1500107            ABETETUBA  GO        NAN  ABAETETUBA
```

Criando uma nova coluna no `DataFrame`.

```
# Criando nova coluna
df['nova_coluna'] = 'NaN'
```

Fazendo a iteração:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['LOCALIDADE'] == row['ds_cidade']:
        df.loc[index,'nova_coluna'] =  str(df.loc[index,'CODIGO'])  

# Apresentando o novo df:
print(df)
```

Saída, para o `df` modificado:

```
    CODIGO           LOCALIDADE  UF cod_cidade   ds_cidade nova_coluna
0  5200050      ABADIA DE GOIAS  GO        NAN  ABAETETUBA         NaN
1  3100104  ABADIA DOS DOURADOS  MG        NAN  ABAETETUBA         NaN
2  5200100             ABADIANA  GO        NAN    ABADIANA     5200100
3  3100203               ABAETE  MG        NAN  ABAETETUBA         NaN
4  1500107            ABETETUBA  GO        NAN  ABAETETUBA         NaN
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-iter-row-chg-col)

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, Sidon! Mas acredito que tenha me expressado de maneira errada. Adicionei ao post uma ilustração do resultado esperado.

Comment: Ainda esta confuso, o resultado esperado q vc colocou não tem nada a ver com o original, fora o fato do que vc não colocou o titulo das colunas no resultado esperado. Insisto para que vc evite as imagens aqui (consegue muito menos respostas dessa forma), tente criar um `df` (minha resposta te ensina como) ficticio tanto para o que vc recebe qto para o que vc espera.

Comment: Ok, fiz uma nova versão adicionando uma coluna nova (`nova_coluna`)  no `df`, só altere o nome dela para o seu contexto.

Comment: Assim que puder testar, posto um retorno aqui!